# Better way of setting default value

Tags: javascript

At the moment I'm setting my default values this way:

```
  var ls = localStorage.get('app')

  if (ls && typeof ls.installDate !== typeof undefined) { var installDate = ls.installDate } else { var installDate = false }
  if (ls && typeof ls.settingsTab !== typeof undefined) { var settingsTab = ls.settingsTab } else { var settingsTab = '' }
  if (ls && typeof ls.aboutTab !== typeof undefined) { var aboutTab = ls.aboutTab } else { var aboutTab = true }
```

plus extra 30 other values. I'm thinking if there is a better (shorter) way to solve this type of approach.

Comment: `var installDate = (ls && ls.installDate) || false`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking to improve working code. ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: the method name must be `getItem('app')` and not `get('app')` :P

Comment: localStorage.get('app') is correct as I'm using custom localstorage library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do the short cut in script as :

```
var ls = localStorage.get('app');
```

You can do like :

```
var installDate = (ls && ls.installDate) || false;
var settingsTab = (ls && ls.settingsTab) || false;
var aboutTab    = (ls.aboutTab) || false;
```

Comment: I don't believe the second and third lines produce the result which the code in the question does.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Please Share the issue which you got while execution

Comment: The OP's default value for `settingsTab` is `''` not `false` (they are not identical, although they may behave the same in many circumstances); the default value for `aboutTab` should be `true`.